# retrieving data from the same table for different users

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new to both programming and database.. I have a common table in mysql accessed by different users,I am using php as the front end,a user can insert ,delete and update information.

**For Example:** if i have 3 users A,B and C,User 'A' should be able to see,update or delete only his data which he have inserted, same shud be done for B and C,and there shud be also a super user where he can see,update or delete given by all the users...

how can i achieve this? and also is it possible to generate the primary key automatically with a prefix like if user A inserts data it shud be A1,A2 and for B it shud be B1,B2 etc..

Comment: do it with multi-tenant setup and auth and with your code. Also, don't get all OCD about the PK's. That will drive you nuts (and us)

Comment: Any article or link where can i find abu this?plz help me

Comment: To steer you toward something you are likely not to mess up by continuing this prefix thing, I suggest ints as PK and FK values. Look up Foreign Key Constraints